# Unable to get past permission denied: docker error

Tags: postgresql, docker

1. Making sure retail_db is either mounted or copied on to the Docker Container.

```
docker run --name retail_pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword -v /Users/fallout/PycharmProjects/Internal/data_copy/retail_pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data -v /Users/fallout/research/data/retail_db_json:/data -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

```
CREATE DATABASE retail_db;
CREATE USER retail_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'something';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE retail_db TO testing;
```

After which I run:

```
docker exec -it retail_pg psql -U testing -d retail_db -f /data/create_db_tables_pg.sql
```

Results in:

```
psql:/data/create_db_tables_pg.sql:12: ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE departments (
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you try using sudo?

Comment: @RichardMcCormick that is - in general - not possible and not desired in docker.

Comment: Could you try adding `\c retail_db; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO testing;` to the init sql?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO user_name;
```

Above is the solution to fix the issue. @Turing85 answered but there is an error in the syntax.